# How to make Package Converter (Alien GUI) work in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: package-management, software-installation

I pretty sure everybody knows Alien (package converter)! rpm to deb, rpm to tgz, deb to tgz, etc. Sadly, no longer maintained, but still working in Ubuntu. But its' GUI named Package Converter doesn't work in Ubuntu 16.04. It installs just fine, but it won't start. Any solution for that???
I'm not such a linux savvy to use Alien in a terminal window, graphical interface would help me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alien syntax is pretty simple.  I didn't even know it had a GUI.  Maybe this will help.

`pwd` Print Working Directory, shows you where you are in the filesystem.  / is the root or base of the filesystem.  You should start off in /home/your_user_name/ when you open a terminal window.

`ls` List, shows what is in the current directory.

`cd` Change Directory, lets you move around the file system.

Download the RPM you want to convert to your Downloads folder, then go there in the terminal like so:

`cd /home/your_user_name/Downloads/
ls -al`

[image: It should look something like this:]

This will take you to your Downloads directory and let you see the file with all it's properties.  With the alien and rpm packages installed do this:

[image: Alien Conversion]

Now you should be able to install it if you have all the dependencies:

`dpkg -i packagename.deb`

Its too bad it isn't maintained any more.  Alien is pretty awesome.

Comment: Although you didn't present an exact solution to my question, i accepted your answer as a satisfactory workaround to my problem. Terminal commands don't seem that scary if you keep it simple. I just wish alien would have support for apks. Just imagine the endless numbers of apps from Google Play "invading" all the linuxes. Ubuntu Software Center would become microscopic compared to GPlay.